# How is P intersection Z a prime ideal of Z?

Tags: ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Here, P is a prime ideal of the polynomial ring Z[x]. Now, how do I show that P intersection Z is a prime ideal of Z?
If P intersection Z is 0, then it is obvious.
If not, then it contains at least one extra element. Suppose P intersection Z = {0,a}, then it is not even an ideal, right?
So, I'm not able to understand, how to prove this lemma!

Comment: If $a$ is in $P\cap \mathbb{Z}$ then so is $2a,3a$, etc. $P \cap \mathbb{Z}$ is definitely an ideal of $\mathbb Z$...

Comment: Okay.. I got it.. thank you